# GoCD cancel stage thru API returns "The resource you requested was not found!"

Tags: api, go-cd

I want to cancel curently running stage and when run:

```
curl "http://go.com/go/api/stages/lab2018.AllTests/183/HarnessSelfTests/1/cancel" -X POST -H 'X-GoCD-Confirm: true' -u "user:password" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json' |  json_pp
```

Basically, I've tried both requests for different versions and both do not work.

```
curl "http://go.com/go/api/stages/lab2018.AllTests/HarnessSelfTests/cancel" -X POST -H 'Confirm: true' -u "user:password" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json' |  json_pp
```

I got:

```
{
   "message" : "The resource you requested was not found!"
}
```

Meanwhile, if I run 'Get stage Instance' with the same parameters:

```
curl "http://go.com/go/api/stages/lab2018.AllTests/HarnessSelfTests/instance/183/1" -X GET -u "user:password" 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json' |  json_pp
```

I got the proper JSON with information about the requested instance.

GoCD version is Go Version: 18.10.0 (7703-42d1cbe661161b5400289ead86c0447c84af8c0a).

GoCD documentation says [Available since v14.3.0](https://api.gocd.org/current/#cancel-stage).

Any proposals what could cause the error? Any ideas how can I debug the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is with `'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v4+json'` header. For the versions less than 19.8.0, this header should not be used. If you use it, it breaks the call. Correct API call:

```
curl "http://go.com/go/api/stages/lab2018.AllTests/HarnessSelfTests/cancel" -X POST -H 'Confirm: true' -u "user:password"
```